# Running shell script with node and current .bashrc

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I'm trying to run a shell script with node.js using spawn of child_process, this works fine, but I need to use some functions created on my .bashrc, let's call it testAll, this is de definition of my function on .bashrc:

```
testAll() {
  echo "I am running the function"
}

export -f testAll()
```

If I call testAll from cmd all works fine, but if I call:

`const child = spawn("testAll", [], { shell: "/bin/bash" });`

I receive an error: /bin/bash: testAll: command not found

I already tried to run this command from a shell script like this:

`const child = spawn("./test.sh", [], { shell: "/bin/bash" });`

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
source /home/myuserhere/.bashrc
echo "teste"

testAll
```

echo shows fine, but I got the same error whit testAll.

I already tried without source, without shopt and with bash ./test.sh and always receive this same error.

Can anyone help me with this tricky error?

Comment: testAll or updateAll is just an example, but thanks I will fix the question